# How to fetch records from last 7 days with padding to 0 if no records found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to fetch records from the last 7 days (may change to support month and year) to populate a chart, and I need to pad the days where no records where found to 0. I first tried grouping but found no way of padding the data, so I came up with this:

```
today = Date.today

array_data = (today - 6.days..today).map do |day|  
  total_time = @project.time_entries.where(created_at: (day.beginning_of_day..day.end_of_day)).map(&:duration_hours).sum

  { day.strftime("%a %d %b") => total_time }
end

@entries_data = array_data.reduce Hash.new, :merge
```

The result is a hash with a day as a key and the sum of a calculated property as the value.

This however, requires a database query for each day:

```
TimeEntry Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "time_entries".* FROM "time_entries" WHERE "time_entries"."project_id" IN ('bd9f541c-e37a-45de-bc94-28bef2b5eade')
  TimeEntry Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "time_entries".* FROM "time_entries" WHERE "time_entries"."project_id" = $1 AND ("time_entries"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-21 04:30:00.000000' AND '2016-03-22 04:29:59.999999')  [["project_id", "bd9f541c-e37a-45de-bc94-28bef2b5eade"]]
  TimeEntry Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "time_entries".* FROM "time_entries" WHERE "time_entries"."project_id" = $1 AND ("time_entries"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-22 04:30:00.000000' AND '2016-03-23 04:29:59.999999')  [["project_id", "bd9f541c-e37a-45de-bc94-28bef2b5eade"]]
  TimeEntry Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "time_entries".* FROM "time_entries" WHERE "time_entries"."project_id" = $1 AND ("time_entries"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-23 04:30:00.000000' AND '2016-03-24 04:29:59.999999')  [["project_id", "bd9f541c-e37a-45de-bc94-28bef2b5eade"]]
  TimeEntry Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "time_entries".* FROM "time_entries" WHERE "time_entries"."project_id" = $1 AND ("time_entries"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-24 04:30:00.000000' AND '2016-03-25 04:29:59.999999')  [["project_id", "bd9f541c-e37a-45de-bc94-28bef2b5eade"]]
  TimeEntry Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "time_entries".* FROM "time_entries" WHERE "time_entries"."project_id" = $1 AND ("time_entries"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-25 04:30:00.000000' AND '2016-03-26 04:29:59.999999')  [["project_id", "bd9f541c-e37a-45de-bc94-28bef2b5eade"]]
  TimeEntry Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "time_entries".* FROM "time_entries" WHERE "time_entries"."project_id" = $1 AND ("time_entries"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-26 04:30:00.000000' AND '2016-03-27 04:29:59.999999')  [["project_id", "bd9f541c-e37a-45de-bc94-28bef2b5eade"]]
  TimeEntry Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "time_entries".* FROM "time_entries" WHERE "time_entries"."project_id" = $1 AND ("time_entries"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-27 04:30:00.000000' AND '2016-03-28 04:29:59.999999')  [["project_id", "bd9f541c-e37a-45de-bc94-28bef2b5eade"]]
```

How can I rework this to make it send only 1 query to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Not certain this is what you mean, but here's what I think you need to do:

- Run the query getting all data for the last N days.
- Group these records by the day
- Merge this on top of a hash with values of `{ date => 0}` for each of the last N days

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as `tpbowden` mentioned in his answer, I managed to reduce it to 1 query like this:

```
date_format = "%d %b"
entries_last_week = time_entries.group_by { |t| t.created_at.to_date.strftime(date_format) }.map { |k, v| { k => v.map(&:duration_hours).sum } }
entries_hash = entries_last_week.reduce Hash.new, :merge
today = Date.today
days = (today - 6.days..today).map { |day| { day.strftime(date_format) => 0 } }
hash_of_days = days.reduce Hash.new, :merge

hash_of_days.merge(entries_hash)
```